# SSH tunnel to browse localhost, super slow

Tags: ssh-tunneling

To visit sites/services like jupyter notebooks and rstudio-server on my server I make a ssh tunnel and then just browse them in my webbrowser on my local machine, however, since yesterday, all my services are loading so slow in my browser.
Not sure why or where to even start the troubleshooting. I can ssh into the server and look at file etc. I even tried reinstall one of the services yesterday before I realized that all of my services were slow...
Any ideas or recommendations how to troubleshoot this?

Can also add that if I manage to connect to one services (only manage to connect to deluge) in the browser, it seems that once i'm connected the service runs without delays in the browsers. So seems that it's "just" the connecting that takes forever. (several mins)
Can also add that the ports are open on both my remote and local machine.

I just now realized that in my terminal I get the following message:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

The command I used to open up the tunnel:

```
ssh -N -f -L 8787:localhost:8787 myNick@192.168.1.xx
```

Comment: From the fact that just connecting takes a long time, I would suggest looking at your DNS set-up. Even though minutes for a faulty DNS is long, it might be one of the contributing factors. Look at DNS on both server and client side! You might also try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Has any of the hosts enabled IPv6 recently?

Comment: @LjmDullaart I'm not aware that any of the services has enabled IPv6. Chaning to 127.0.0.1 when opening the tunnel seems like it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @LjmDullaart If you want you can add that as a reply and I will accept your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when session set-up is slow, but once the session runs it has acceptable speed, the first thing to look at is the hostname resolution. There are many issues that could cause problems:

- A server and/or DNS suddenly starts using IPv6
- Faulty DNS
- Changes in `/etc/hosts`
- etc.

Using 127.0.0.1 instead of the hostname bypasses most of these problems (but does not solve them!), for example:

```
ssh -N -f -L 8787:127.0.0.1:8787 myNick@192.168.1.xx
```

Comment: Okay, however I do have `127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain   localhost` entry in `/etc/hosts` and can't find any other problems with my DNS?

Comment: At the client side but also at the server-side? Has `127.0.0.1`  been assigned with the hostname as well (shouldn't be, but some installations do that) , either at server or at the client? (just another option that is part of the 'etc.' at the end of the list)

Comment: Without doing anything really, it seems to work fine even with localhost now. Also that localhost entry was on the server-side.